# 2GP sfdx project structure strategy

Tags: salesforcedx, 2gp

We have multiple 2GP managed package coming out of our current monolith 1GP package. which is a better salesforce 2gp project structure strategy, multiple package directory in same sfdx project versus single sfdx project for each 2GP package?

Comment: This is going to get opinionated answers, so not ideal for this forum. I know that Salesforce like what they call "mono-repo" - a single repo with package directories for multiple 2GP managed packages in the same namespace. It has the advantage of immediate detection of name clashes and avoids the need to install dependency packages, for example. However, I don't believe it detects use of APIs not marked as NamespaceAccessible. I personally prefer separate projects, but have only used that for distinct extension packages at this point (rather than decomposition of 1GP monolith).

Comment: Thanks @PhilW for the insight